# Waterline insert one to many association with return id

Tags: node.js, waterline

I have two models, Document and File, each Document can have many Files while each File can only belong to one Document (one to many).

I have the following code to trying to insert one File. Waterline will return the Document modal with all associated Files, but what I want is just the last insert ID of the File that I just inserted.

```
Document.findOne({hash: documentHash}).exec(function(err, document) {           
    if (err) {return res.serverError(err);}                                                                     

    document.files.add({
        name: req.param("name"),
        creator: req.param("userID");
    });

    document.save(function(err, model) {
        if (err) {return res.serverError(err);}

        //it returned the Document modal, but I want the last insert id
        console.log(model);  
        res.send(1);                                            
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid `document.save()` only returns a populated version of `model`. You can see all files in `model.files` but then it would be up to you to figure out which was the last one.

One alternative is to create the file before adding it to document. You should be able to do:

```
//...

File.create({
  name: req.param("name"),
  creator: req.param("userID");
}, function(err, file){
  if (err) {return res.serverError(err);}

  var newFileId = file.id;
  document.files.add(file.id);
  document.save(function(err, model) {
    if (err) {return res.serverError(err);}

    // the Document modal
    console.log(model);
    // the last insert id
    console.log('last inserted id:', newFileId);  
    res.send(1);                                            
  });
});

//...
```

In this case `newFileId` will have the id you need. Performance wise it should be the same as internally waterline has to create the file in similar way.